# jQuery - IE8 - fadeIn() / fadeOut() pixel shifting

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I'm replacing one absolutely positioned dictionary term  with another like so:

jQuery('#replaceme').fadeOut(150, function() {
    jQuery('#withme').fadeIn(150);
});

It's pretty simple code that looks and works great in all browsers except IE8. In IE8, while fadeOut() is doing its thing, the entire text block shifts up 2-3 pixels, and then back down 2-3 pixels upon fadeIn().

Any ideas on what may be causing this? Anybody know a way to prevent this from happening?

BTW: I get the same results with jQuery 1.3.1 as I do with 1.3.2. All of my strict XHTML and CSS validate.

Answer (score 1):

is it changing from an inline element to an inline-block or block element?

using the ie8 developer tools, try changing the display property of the element to `display:inline-block` and see if the problem occurs then.

edit: response to comments

what's likely happening is the element is being taken out of the expected document flow (appended to body, or a new parent is insert and this is appended to that, etc..) and the css rules that would normally apply do not in this case.

use firebug to identify all of the css rules applying to this element, then try adding this element id, #replaceme, to the list of selectors to guarantee that element is getting styled the way you expect.
e.g.

```
dt > dd.def { }
```

becomes

```
dt > dd.def, #replaceme { }
```

Comment: Each dictionary definition <dd> is a block level element with a heading, image and paragraph tag within it. They're all absolutely positioned in the same spot and set to: display: none; by default.  When the user clicks on a <dt> the definitions swap...the current definition fades out and then new one fades in.

Comment: Jonathon, thanks so much for the help. As it turns out, there was nothing wrong with the CSS for the definition list. The site's header div was styled to be 100px high and there was an element whose bottom margin extended past that height. Apparantly that margin was throwing off IE8 while performing the jQuery fades.